# Can't create many to many relationship in ef core with ApplicationUser

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a many to many relationship between ApplicationUser and Courses in my application but I'm getting the following error when attempting to insert a record into the CourseUsers table:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_CourseUsers_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database
> "PIL", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

I can't figure out what the issue is. I've followed the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

My user model:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActive { get; set; }
    public List<CourseUser> CourseUsers { get; set; }
    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

My course model:

```
    public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public string PreviewVideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string Topics { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public List<CourseContributor> CourseContributors { get; set; }
    public List<CourseUser> CourseUsers { get; set; }
    public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public string Grades { get; set; }
}
```

My lookup model:

```
    public class CourseUser
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

My DataContext:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contributor> Contributors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseContributor>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.CourseId, c.ContributorId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseContributor>()
            .HasOne(cc => cc.Contributor)
            .WithMany(c => c.CourseContributors)
            .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.ContributorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseContributor>()
            .HasOne(cc => cc.Course)
            .WithMany(c => c.CourseContributors)
            .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.CourseId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseUser>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.CourseId, c.UserId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseUser>()
            .HasOne(u => u.User)
            .WithMany(c => c.CourseUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(us => us.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseUser>()
            .HasOne(cc => cc.Course)
            .WithMany(c => c.CourseUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.CourseId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Lesson>().HasData(new Lesson() { Id = 1, Title = "Test Lesson", SubTitle = "Test Lesson Title", Description = "Test Lesson Description", DocUrl = "fdsafdsffds", ThumbnailUrl = "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/stack-of-books-picture-id157482029?s=612x612", VideoUrl = "testVideoUrl", CourseId = 1 });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contributor>().HasData(new Contributor() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Test First Name", LastName = "Test Last Name" });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasData(new Course() { Id = 1, Title = "Test Course", Subtitle = "Test Course Title", Description = "Test Course Description", Cost = 20.00M, Grades = "1,2,3", PreviewVideoUrl = "Test Preview Video Url", ThumbnailUrl = "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/stack-of-books-picture-id157482029?s=612x612", Topics = "Test Topic 1|Test Topic 2|Test Topic 3" });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseContributor>().HasData(new CourseContributor() { CourseId = 1, ContributorId = 1 });
        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseUser>().HasData(new CourseUser() { CourseId = 1, UserId = "1234" });
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the User seeding method

```
    public class Seed
{
    public static void SeedUsers(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        if (!userManager.Users.Any())
        {
            userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser { Id = "1234", UserName = "test@test.org", Created = DateTime.UtcNow, LastActive = DateTime.UtcNow, Email = "test@test.org" }, "Password1!").Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

And Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
                Seed.SeedUsers(userManager);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: What's your tables DDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really an issue here with the model you defined. Its just your test data, that is incomplete.

Add the following line to your `OnModelCreating()` method:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(new ApplicationUser {Id = "1234"});
```

Comment: Hi lauxjpn. I forgot to add my user seeding logic to the post. Please see the edit with the information

Comment: Looks like your `SeedUsers()` method gets called too late. The exception you are getting is complaining, that your `HasData()` method adds a `CourseUser` with a FK to a non-existing `AspNetUser` / `ApplicationUser`. If you want to use the `HasData()` methods, then the user must either already exist wenn the `HasData()` calls are made, or must be added together with the other `HasData()` calls. The simplest way to do that is to add the line I posted. The other `HasData()` calls are seeding methods as well, so why do something special for the user? After all, this is no production code anyhow.

Comment: I thought I had already tried the equivalent of that but had no success. Some other factor must have been breaking it originally. Nevertheless, this has worked! Thank you sir.